# Positioning elements with dataTables dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I'm trying to change places of records button to bottom but I want fix search bar in top I tried this but this moving all top to bottom.

```
"dom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
```

What should I do ?

Comment: By "places of records button" you mean the dropdown menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved my problem with this code.

```
"dom": '<"top"if>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I use on one of my websites.

I have a datatable that sits inside of an overflow div. I wanted to have my search bar outside of this div so that when scrolling the overflow the search bar remains still and wont scroll with the datatable.

I created my own textbox to serve as the search tool and then connected that to the datatable search function.

```
<label><strong>Search: </strong><input type="text" id="myInputTextField"
</label>
<div class="grid_container">
    <table id="datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>heading1</th>
                <th>Heading 2</th>
            </tr>
        <thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data1</td>
                <td>data2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

Then my jquery for creating the datatable looks like

```
$(function(){
  $('#datatable').DataTable({
      "paging": true,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "lengthMenu": [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
      "order": [[0, 'desc']],
      "sDom": '<"top">l<"grid_container" t>ip'
  });
  var oTable = $('#datatable').DataTable();
  $('#myInputTextField').keyup(function () {
      oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
  })
```

})

Where the first part of the function is the normal datatable settings. And the second part of the function is associating my search textbox with the datatable search function on each keyup in the textbox.